Direct Multi-Step Forecasting by each day of the week?
I am looking to create a daily 7 day forecast for a particular domain problem.
Currently I have a recursive solution, which hasn't been performing too well.
I have also looked into direct forecasting approaches. But how does this work if my forecast is being run for a different day of the week? I ask this as my data has some strong weekly seasonalities.
Would it make sense to have a model (i.e. LightGBM) for each day of the week Monday to Sunday? However I see this causing issues at inference time if I'm running the forecast on different days of the week, particularly trying to figure out what a consistent set of input features would look like.
P.S. I'm interested in using ML as I'd like to model a large set of items, across multiple locations, while modelling the effects of other factors (weather, events etc.).
Thank you in advance 
